# Delphi существует ли способ работы с WebP без dll

Tags: delphi

1. На VDS будет стоять програ и конвертить фотки. но на VDS TWICImage не хочет работать с WebP
   хотя на моей машине все работает. Если использовать libwebp.dll то и на VDS все работает
   но я не хочу за прогой тягать dll. Есть ли модуль где нет Dll и он работает с WebP?
2. Почему на VDS не работает класс TWICImage с WebP но Jpg работает.
   Что не хватает на VDS. Какие библиотеки системные нужны.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно скопировать со своего компа C:\Program Files\Windows Photo Viewer
и поместить на VDS тогда TWICImage будет работать

Comment: т.е. это лучше, чем dll-ку положить?

Comment: @MBo да пошел за хлебом купил пол магазина.